# How do I query the length of a Django ArrayField?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I have an ArrayField in a model, I'm trying to annotate the length of this field ( so far without any luck)

`F('field_name__len')` won't work since join is not allowed inside `F()`.  Even 
`ModelName.objets.values('field_name__len')` is not working

Any idea?

I'm using **django 1.11**

Comment: can you post the the content of the column you are trying to query

Comment: `[112,113,114,115,116,117]`  for example

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `extra()` function has been deprecated according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra):

> Use this method as a last resort
>
> This is an old API that we aim to deprecate at some point in the future. Use it only if you cannot express your query using other queryset methods.

Here is how you can do the same thing using a custom `Annotation` function:

```
from django.db import models

class ArrayLength(models.Func):
    function = 'CARDINALITY'

MyModel.objects.all().annotate(field_len=ArrayLength('field')).order_by('field_len')
```

Note that the [`cardinality()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/release-9-4.html#AEN123014) function is available in PostgreSQL 9.4 or later. If you're using an older version, you have to use [`array_length()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-array.html):

```
MyModel.objects.all().annotate(field_len=Func(F('field'), 1, function='array_length')).order_by('field_len')
```

One caveat with this second query is that an empty array will be sorted in front of all non-empty ones. This could be solved by coalescing `NULL` values from `array_length` to 0.

Comment: Great answer! Just wanted to note that we can also use the function directly: `.annotate(field_len=Func(F('field'), function='CARDINALITY')) `

Comment: Note that if you're using [`django-postgres-extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/django-postgres-extensions/) you already have both [`Cardinality`](https://github.com/primal100/django_postgres_extensions/blob/bb1edc2cbf194fe571a605595a898b2528918301/django_postgres_extensions/models/functions.py#L86) and [`ArrayLength`](https://github.com/primal100/django_postgres_extensions/blob/bb1edc2cbf194fe571a605595a898b2528918301/django_postgres_extensions/models/functions.py#L74) functions.

Answer (score 6):

```
ModelName.objects.extra(select={'length':'cardinality(field_name)'}).order_by('length')
```

you can try this

Answer (score 6):

## Tested on django 3.5, your query now works!

I'm not sure which version added this offhand, but give it a try, or try upgrading if you can.

```
ModelName.objects.values('field_name__len')

<ModelName [{'field_name__len': 1}]>
```

Also some other things to try:

```
ModelName.objects.filter(field_name__len__gt=0)
ModelName.objects.filter(field_name__len__gte=0)
ModelName.objects.filter(field_name__len=0)
ModelName.objects.filter(field_name__len__lte=10)
ModelName.objects.filter(field_name__len__lt=10)
```

Comment: This feature is available since Django 2.0 at least. Link to the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#len